# Why this variable act as a object?

Tags: php

I am very new in programming world. It may it's a very silly question. But I need a clear concept about this issue that's why I am asking this question.

```
<?php 
  $json = '{"a":1}';
  $data = json_decode($json);
  echo $data->a; 
?>
```

I have learn when we called a object that should be

```
$data = new json_decode($json);
```

Why this `$data` worked as a object without `new` ?

Comment: You need to pass another parameter `true` to get it as an `assoc array`

Comment: My question is why it's working as a object ?

Comment: Its because `json_decode` **Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.**. Check [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for how `json_decode` works

Comment: `json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )` if you can notice $assoc = false by default, that means you are restricting the conversion from object to array .

Answer (score 1):

That is a json array, it can be converted to an object or to an associative array. 
If you use the function

```
$object = json_decode($array);
```

the destination variable will be treated as an object. 
If your will is just to decode to a json array to an associative array you have to add a true after the array

```
$assArray= json_decode($array,true);
```

In this case you can access the values as a normal array

```
echo($assArray["a"]);
```

Will output 1.

However I suggest you to check the official manual, is very clear in the explanation of these function

[PHP Official manual json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store it inside a variable to use like an array.

```
<?php 
  $json = '{"a":1}';
  $data = json_decode($json,true);
  echo $data['a']; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `json_decode` (without providing second parameter) will return you object, which means that the function itself will create (and return) new `stdClass` for you.

If you want array instead:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use a function that returning an instance.

When you use **new** operator, you create an instance explicitely from className. With examples :

```
function return_instance() {
    return new ClassName();
}
$obj1 = return_instance();
$obj2 = new ClassName();
// The two objects return the same type of object
```

Comment: Yes. It's his goal. You want convert JSON to object (or another type according documentation http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) by default attempts to return an object rather than an array.  In doing so you don't need to `new` json_decode, rather just call the function directly.  You can return an array by adding a second parameter `true`.

For example:

```
$asObject = json_decode($jsonText);
$asArray = json_decode($jsonText, true);
```

The `new` keyword essentially invokes a class's constructor to create a new object.  If you like, you can think of `json_decode` as calling `new` inside the function so to create a new object for you.

Answer (score 0):

becouse json_deocde return type is of object type here is example

```
 function jsonDecode($json){
  //here logic of decoding;
   return new stdClass();

 }
```

now it will type of object